# how to pass multiple lists of distributions to sklearn randomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, shogun

I have a customized estimator object in Python (`mkl_regressor`). One of the learning parameters of such an object is a `numpy.array` of floats. Usually sklearn estimator objects are tuned by single parameters, like the `C` of a SVM. Thus the `randomizedSearchCV` search object takes a distribution or a list of values for picking up some value from the given distribution (in my example is `scipy.stats.expon`) for the desired parameter. I have tried to pass a list of distributions, but I had not success, because `randomizedSearchCV` does not execute the elements in the array of distributions. This is what I tried:

```
from modshogun import *
import Gnuplot, Gnuplot.funcutils
from numpy import *
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

class mkl_regressor():

    def __init__(self, widths = [0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 50.0, 100.0], kernel_weights = [0.01, 0.1, 1.0,], svm_c = 0.01, mkl_c = 1.0, svm_norm = 1, mkl_norm = 1, degree = 2):
        self.svm_c = svm_c
        self.mkl_c = mkl_c
        self.svm_norm = svm_norm
        self.mkl_norm = mkl_norm
        self.degree = degree
        self.widths = widths
        self.kernel_weights = kernel_weights


    def fit(self, X, y, **params):
        for parameter, value in params.items():
            setattr(self, parameter, value)        

        self.feats_train = RealFeatures(X.T)
        labels_train = RegressionLabels(y.reshape((len(y), )))
        self._kernels_  = CombinedKernel()
        for width in self.widths:
            kernel = GaussianKernel()
            kernel.set_width(width)
            kernel.init(self.feats_train,self.feats_train)
            self._kernels_.append_kernel(kernel)
            del kernel

        kernel = PolyKernel(10, self.degree)            
        self._kernels_.append_kernel(kernel)
        del kernel

        self._kernels_.init(self.feats_train, self.feats_train)

        binary_svm_solver = SVRLight()
        self.mkl = MKLRegression(binary_svm_solver)

        self.mkl.set_C(self.svm_c, self.svm_c)
        self.mkl.set_C_mkl(self.mkl_c)
        self.mkl.set_mkl_norm(self.mkl_norm)
        self.mkl.set_mkl_block_norm(self.svm_norm)

        self.mkl.set_kernel(self._kernels_)
        self.mkl.set_labels(labels_train)
        self.mkl.train()
        self.kernel_weights = self._kernels_.get_subkernel_weights()

    def predict(self, X):
        self.feats_test = RealFeatures(X.T)
        self._kernels_.init(self.feats_train, self.feats_test) 
        self.mkl.set_kernel(self._kernels_)
        return self.mkl.apply_regression().get_labels()

    def set_params(self, **params):
        for parameter, value in params.items():
            setattr(self, parameter, value)

        return self

    def get_params(self, deep=False):

        return {param: getattr(self, param) for param in dir(self) if not param.startswith('__') and not callable(getattr(self,param))}    

    def score(self,  X_t, y_t):

        predicted = self.predict(X_t)
        return r2_score(predicted, y_t)    

if __name__ == "__main__":

    from sklearn.grid_search import RandomizedSearchCV as RS
    from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint
    from scipy.stats import expon

    labels = array([2.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,3.0,2.0])
    labels = labels.reshape((len(labels), 1))
    data = array([[1.0,2.0,3.0],[1.0,2.0,9.0],[1.0,2.0,3.0],[1.0,2.0,0.0],[0.0,2.0,3.0],[1.0,2.0,3.0]])
    labels_t = array([1.,3.,4])
    labels_t = labels_t.reshape((len(labels_t), 1))
    data_t = array([[20.0,30.0,40.0],[10.0,20.0,30.0],[10.0,20.0,40.0]])
    k = 3

    param_grid = [ {'svm_c': expon(scale=100, loc=5),
                'mkl_c': expon(scale=100, loc=5),
                'degree': sp_randint(0, 32),
                #'widths': [array([4.0,6.0,8.9,3.0]), array([4.0,6.0,8.9,3.0,2.0, 3.0, 4.0]), array( [100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0]) 
                'widths': [[expon, expon]] 
              }]

    mkl = mkl_regressor()
    rs = RS(mkl, param_distributions = param_grid[0], n_iter = 10, n_jobs = 24, cv = k)#, scoring="r2", verbose=True)
    rs.fit(data, labels)
    preds = rs.predict(data_t)

    print "R^2: ", rs.score(data_t, labels_t)
    print "Parameters: ", rs.best_params_
```

The above code works well by passing numpy arrays as elements of the list `'widths'` of the dictionary of parameters. However, when I try to pass a list of distributions, the randomizedSearchCV object does not respond as desired:

```
/home/ignacio/distributionalSemanticStabilityThesis/mkl_test.py in fit(self=<__main__.mkl_regressor instance>, X=array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.]]), y=array([[ 2.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 2.]]), **params={})
     24         self.feats_train = RealFeatures(X.T)
     25         labels_train = RegressionLabels(y.reshape((len(y), )))
     26         self._kernels_  = CombinedKernel()
     27         for width in self.widths:
     28             kernel = GaussianKernel()
---> 29             kernel.set_width(width)
        kernel.set_width = <built-in method set_width of GaussianKernel object>
        width = <scipy.stats._continuous_distns.expon_gen object>
     30             kernel.init(self.feats_train,self.feats_train)
     31             self._kernels_.append_kernel(kernel)
     32             del kernel
     33 

TypeError: in method 'GaussianKernel_set_width', argument 2 of type 'float64_t'
```

I wouldn't like to force the estimator for executing each distribution generator because in such a case, the `randomizedSearchCV` wouldn't has control of the used values.

Some suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RandomizedSearchCV can take either a **list of parameter values to try** or a **distribution object with an rvs method for sampling**. If you pass it a list, it will assume you passed a discrete set of parameter values to sample from. It does not support a list of distributions for a single parameter. If existing distributions don't suit your needs, make a custom one.

If you need a distribution that returns an array, simply create a class that has an rvs() method to return a random sample and pass an instance of that instead of a list of single-variate distributions.

Comment: Hi @bpachev, thank you for answer. It is needed because the estimator object I posted (MKL) requires extra parameters. These parameters are different kernel bandwidths, i.e. a vector of bandwidths (not only one, as in the case of an SVR for instance), which is not of fixed length. Some suggestion for give to `RandomizedSearchCV` the control of what is being sampled for each component of the vector of bandwidths? I'm currently generating random vectors before passing them to `RandomizedSearchCV`, but it is a very inefficient solution.

Comment: You need to create a distribution function that returns arrays with the proper distribution.I'll edit by answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The solution @bpachev suggested worked for me. The distribution class:

```
class expon_vector(stats.rv_continuous):

    def __init__(self, loc = 1.0, scale = 50.0, min_size=2, max_size = 10):
        self.loc = loc
        self.scale = scale
        self.min_size = min_size
        self.max_size = max_size
        self.size = max_size - min_size # Only for initialization

    def rvs(self):

        self.size = randint.rvs(low = self.min_size, 
                                high = self.max_size, size = 1)
        return expon.rvs(loc  = self.loc, scale = self.scale, size = self.size)
```

Which is included in the dictionary of parameters for the customized estimator I'm using:

```
param_grid = [ {'svm_c': expon(scale=100, loc=5),
                    'mkl_c': expon(scale=100, loc=5),
                    'degree': sp_randint(0, 24),
                    'widths': expon_vector(loc = 0.1, scale = 100.0, 
                              min_size = 2, max_size = 10) } ]
```